# rails nested forms parts doesn't save altough the are permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

i am programming in rails 4. I have done a nested form that addsnested attribuets by JavaScript , following 
[railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2).

I have a `feast`. it has many `dishes` through `courses` and `users` through `participations`.
each users get `feast` assignments like that :
participations has many `dishes` through `obligations`.

My question is : why does it not save? the feast saves but the nested form parts do not...
 basically I guess it is a problem with strong params somehow, or it should be in the controller or model. so I pasted them first . I pasted the HTML generated by the program - only the relevant part at the end so to make the question not too long somehow.
thanks

this is the code:

```
Class Feast < ActiveRecord::Base

mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader


has_many :participations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, :through => :participations

has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy
has_many :dishes, :through => :courses


accepts_nested_attributes_for :participations,
:allow_destroy => true

accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses,
:allow_destroy => true
```

and participations:

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :feast

  has_many :obligations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :dishes, :through=> :obligations
  has_many :groceries, :as => :needed 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :obligations,
  :allow_destroy => true


end
```

the program is complicated so in the end I of this question I will post the HTML created for one participant ,one dish and one assignment(=obligation) just so it is seen that the program works fine.

here are my nested forms - their values are updated and inserted by js.
course fields partial:

```
<%= link_to_function "remove","remove_fields_dish(this)", :class => "cl_both" %>    
<%new_object = Feast.reflect_on_association(:courses).klass.new%>
<%= f.fields_for(:courses, new_object, child_index: "new_course", class: "fields") do     
|fc| %>
    <%=fc.hidden_field(:dish_id)%> 
    <%=fc.hidden_field(:_destroy,value: false)%>
<%end%>
```

participation fields partial:

```
<%= link_to_function "remove","remove_fields_dish(this)", :class => "cl_both" %>    
 <%new_object = Feast.reflect_on_association(:participations).klass.new%>
 <%= f.fields_for(:participations, new_object , child_index: "new_course", class: "fields") do    
|fc| %>
    <%=fc.hidden_field(:dish_id)%> 
    <%=fc.hidden_field(:_destroy,value: false)%>
<%end%>
```

obligation fields partial:

```
 <%new_object = Participations.reflect_on_association(:obligations).klass.new%>
 <%= fp.fields_for(:obligations, new_object , child_index: "new_obli", class:    
     "fields") do |fpo| %>
        <%= fpo.hidden_field(:dish_id) %> 
        <%= fpo.hidden_field(:_destroy,value: false) %>
     <%end%>
```

my controller feasts_controller:

```
class FeastsController < ApplicationController

 def list
   @user_feast_m=Feast.joins(participations: :user).where(participations: {manager:    
    true}).to_a
   @user_feast_p=Feast.joins(participations: :user).where(participations: {manager:    
    false}).to_a
 end

  def show
     @feast=feast.find(params[:id])
     @users=@feast.users
     @dishes=(Dish.joins(obligations: {participation: :feast}).where(feast:   
     {id:@feast.id }).to_a + @feast.dishes).compact
  end

  def new

    @feast= Feast.new
    @myself = User.find(session[:user_id])
     respond_to do |format| 
      format.html 
      format.js 
    end
  end  

  def create
    @feast = Feast.new(feast_params)
    if @feast.save
    flash[:notice]="the feast has been saved. all participants will get invitations and    
    assignments. hope they answer soon"
    redirect_to(:action=>'list')
    else
      render('new')
    end
 end

  def update
  end

  def edit
    @feast=feast.find(params[:id])
    @users=@feast.users.sort{|user1,user2| user2.manager <=>   
    user1.manager}.sort_by{|user| user.name}    
    @dishes=(Dish.joins(obligations: {participation: :feast}).where(feast:   
    {id:@feast.id }).to_a + @feast.dishes).compact
  end

  def delete
     @feast=Feast.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
  end 


private 

   def feast_params
       params.require(:feast).permit(:id, :name, :image, :feast_place,    
       :feast_time,courses_attributes: [:id, 
       :dish_id,:_destroy,:feast_id],participations_attributes: [:id,:feast_id, 
       :user_id, :_destroy],obligations_attributes: [:id, :dish_id, :_destroy, 
       :participation_id])
   end

 end
```

this is the HTML generated:

```
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/feasts/create" enctype="multipart/form-data"     
   method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8"    
 type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" 
 value="llJ73mQ6yIZHKvs1EDHnVbjc1nIGlWN2eCirXwiCgCs="></div>

 #+> some input fields for the feast goes here
<br><br>
    <label for="feast_feast place">feast_place</label><br><br>
    <input id="feast_feast_place" name="feast[feast_place]" type="text"> <br><br>
    upload image file <br><br>
    <input id="feast_image" name="feast[image]" type="file"> <br><br>

<h2>participants

   <u>
        <a class="right" data-content="<br />
         <a class="cl_both" href="#"   
         onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;">remove</a>    

    <input id="feast_participations_user_id" name=";feast[participations][user_id]"   
    type="hidden" /> 
    <input id="feast_participations__destroy" name="feast[participations][_destroy]" 
    type="hidden" value="false" />
    <div data-obcontent='


    <input id="feast_participations_obligations_attributes_new_obli_dish_id" 
    name="feast[participations][obligations_attributes][new_obli][dish_id]"   
    type="hidden"/> 
    <input id="feast_participations_obligations_attributes_new_obli__destroy" 
    name="feast[participations][obligations_attributes][new_obli][_destroy]" 
    type="hidden" value="false" />





' >

    </div>



" href="#" id="try" onclick="add_par(); return false;">
     <img alt="Photo Gallery" height="100" src="/assets/add_participants.png"   
  width="100">

 </a>    </u>
  </h2> 

 <br><br><br>    

<div data-myid="3" data-myimage=""image":{"url:"/uploads/user/image/3/el4.jp"}}" data-   
 myname="elad bezalel" id="par">
    <table>
        <tbody><tr>
            <th>participant</th>
            <th>assignment</th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><div class="user_block ui-droppable" style=""><a href="/users/show?  
                  id=7" id="1404733550784"><img alt="user picture" 
                  src="/uploads/user/image/7/Yemenite.gif" height="100" width="100">
                <br>amit</a><br>
                <a class="cl_both" href="#" onclick="remove_fields(this); return 
                false;">remove</a>  

                <input id="1404733550977" name="feast[participations][user_id]" 
                 type="hidden" value="7"> 



                <input id="1404733554049" name="feast[participations]
                [obligations_attributes][1404733554050][dish_id]" type="hidden" 
                 value="140473354199"> 

    <input id= "feast_participations_obligations_attributes_1404733554050__destroy"   
     name="feast[participations][obligations_attributes][1404733554050][_destroy]" 
     type="hidden" value="false">







        <input id="feast_participations__destroy" name="feast[participations]
        [_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false">
        <div data-obcontent="


        <input id="feast_participations_obligations_attributes_new_obli_dish_id"    
         name="feast[participations][obligations_attributes][new_obli][dish_id]"  
         type="hidden" ></div> 
        <input id="feast_participations_obligations_attributes_new_obli__destroy"   
        name="feast[participations][obligations_attributes][new_obli][_destroy]"  
        type="hidden" value="false" />





    ">

    </div>



    </div></td><td><dfn>e&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</dfn><img   
    alt="cancel - x" class="x-pic" height="30" src="/assets/x-blue.png" width="30"> 
    </td></tr></tbody></table>




  </div>
   <br><br><br><br><br><br>

 <h2>dishes
    <u>
         <a class="right" data-content="<br />
   <a class="cl_both" href='#' onclick='remove_fields_dish(this); return    
   false'>remove</a>    

    <input id="feast_courses_dish_id" name="feast[courses][dish_id]" type="hidden" /> 
    <input id="feast_courses__destroy" name="feast[courses][_destroy]"type="hidden"   
  value="false" />

" href="#" id="add_course" onclick="add_course(); return false;">
     <img alt="Photo Gallery" height="100" src="/assets/add_dish.png" width="100">
  </a>    </u>
  </h2> 

  <br><br><br>   

    <div id="course">
        <table>

            <tbody><tr><td><div class="dish_block ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"    
     style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><a href="/dishes/show?id=9"   
     id="1404733541991"><img alt="dish picture"   
    src="/uploads/dish/image/9/IMG_0012.JPG" height="100" width="100"><br>e</a><br>

   <a class="cl_both" href="#" onclick="remove_fields_dish(this); return   
   false;">remove</a>   

    <input id="1404733542182" name="feast[courses][dish_id]" type="hidden" value="9"> 
    <input id="feast_courses__destroy" name="feast[courses][_destroy]" type="hidden"   
   value="false">

</div></td></tr></tbody></table>        
</div>  
 <br><br>
 <input name="commit" type="submit" value="initiate feast">
 </form>
```

why does the nested parts not save?

Comment: The problem is you are not building your child records along with the parent.In your `new` method of your controller you should have `@feast.participations.build` and `@feast.courses.build`.

Comment: in rails casts rayn builds the new child record by a link. so he writes <%new_object = Feast.reflect_on_association(:courses).klass.new%>
<%= f.fields_for(:courses, new_object, child_index: "new_course", class: "fields") do |fc| %> and so i tried to do now in my partial but it still doesn't work.... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here it goes:
i tried 2 plugins and they didn't work so i figured that i am doing something wrong with the 
general form.

i used matched routes . as i changed to REST routes everything works fine.

probebly the previous form decleration line :

```
   <%= form_for(:feast, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
```

was lacking the @feast variable so it can append to it the nested parts.
so maybe there is a way to fix it even with matched routes maybe something like:

```
   <%= form_for(:feast, @feast, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
```

but since 
i change to REST routes its working and i don't bother to check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the problem, but here are some things I would do to debug and narrow down your issue:

- In your controller, `raise feast_params.inspect`. Do that match your expectations?
- In a `rails console` session, try to create nested models (`Feast.new(participations_attributes: {...})`).